# Solving two equations involving Gamma functions where Reduce does not work

Tags: equation-solving

In the following lines of code, we are trying to compute the L-moment   estimates of the parameters of the [`Kumaraswamy distribution`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/KumaraswamyDistribution.html). But as you notice, neither [`NSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NSolve.html) nor [`Reduce`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reduce.html) work. Interestingly, Mathematica has inbuilt method of moments which very similar to solving the following two equations

```
 Reduce[
   l1 - (β Gamma[1 + 1/α] Gamma[β])/Gamma[1 + 1/α + β] == 0 && 
   l2 - l1 + 2 (β Gamma[1 + 1/α] Gamma[2 β])/Gamma[1 + 1/α + 2 β] == 0, 
   {α, β}]
```

> ```
>  Reduce[
>    0.5296881355 - (β Gamma[1 + 1/α] Gamma[β])/Gamma[1 + 1/α + β] == 0 && 
>    -0.4161213389 + (2 β Gamma[1 + 1/α] Gamma[2 β])/Gamma[1 + 1/α + 2 β] == 0, 
>    {α, β}]
> ```

Comment: Why not use `FindRoot`?

Comment: @CarlWoll : That is working too!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This

```
NMinimize[
  Norm[ 0.5296881355-(β Gamma[1+1/α] Gamma[β])/ Gamma[1+1/α+β]]+
  Norm[-0.4161213389 + (2 β Gamma[1 + 1/α] Gamma[2 β])/Gamma[1 + 1/α + 2 β]],
  {α, β}]
```

returns this

```
  {2.22045*^-16, {α->2.4188, β->2.75976}}
```

in an instant.

That technique can also often provide useful information when there likely is no solution by showing that it found a significantly non-zero minimum